# Downloading and displaying thumbnails from bing

Tags: php

I’m trying to do 2 things:

1)  Get thumbnails from Bing and display it. The URL looks like this `http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M764a682297c84c4e519c91b4d39a5731o0`

I tried doing the following but it didn’t work.

```
<?php
    $file = 'http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M764a682297c84c4e519c91b4d39a5731o0';

    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    echo file_get_contents($file);
?>
```

2. the second thing I’m trying to do is to download thumbnails from bing (the same as the previous URL)

> ```
>     <?php
>
> $content = file_get_contents('http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M27a2faeba4dbe75a45036d09675745dfH0&h=200&w=210');
>
> echo file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $content);
>  ?>
> ```

Non of the above worked, it might be cause the URL doesn't end with a JPEG extension but I'm not sure. any ideas how can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: unlikely bing allows you to scrape it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first try, you write `filesize($file)`, but `$file` is a string, not a file. So your header is `Content-Length: False`. In addition,if you have error reporting enabled, your script echoes something like “Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for ...” that corrupt JPEG output.

In your second try, you save the content to a local file, then you echo the result of `file_get_contents`, that is an integer, as you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

First retrieve contents, then output it:

```
$file = 'http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M764a682297c84c4e519c91b4d39a5731o0';

$data = file_get_contents( $file );

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
echo $data;
exit;
```

Tested as working.

Comment: I just tested it, it didn't work. the out put was something like this:����JFIF``��C    $ &%# #"(-90(*6+"#2D26;=@@@&0FKE>J9?@=��C  =)#)==================================================��,�"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*

Comment: The script works. Double ckeck-it. Also note that NO OTHER output is allowed. Even a single space before opening `<?php` tag will corrupt your JPG. Check in browser source if there are some warnings.

Answer (score 0):

<a:clrMap xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" bg1="lt1" tx1="dk1" bg2="lt2" tx2="dk2" accent1="accent1" accent2="accent2" accent3="accent3" accent4="accent4" accent5="accent5" accent6="accent6" hlink="hlink" folHlink="folHlink"/>

Comment: Posting code-only answers is highly discouraged. Please provide some context on how your code solves the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).